# Python numpy array math showing weird results

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

The last cell of the bellow array shows a wrong result:

Code:

```
import numpy
b=numpy.array ([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,8,16]])
b=b**b/b+1
b
```

result:

```
array([[2.000000e+00, 3.000000e+00, 1.000000e+01, 6.500000e+01],
       [6.260000e+02, 7.777000e+03, 2.097153e+06, 1.000000e+00]])
```

All numbers are correct except for the last one.

Type is `numpy.float64`. The correct answer is `1.152921504606847e+18`.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you construct a `numpy` array with whole numbers, its type will be `int32` or `int64` depending on your system, instead of the `float64` you expected. So when you do `16**16`, the result overflowed and you end up with a 0.

To fix this, specify the `float64` type for your numpy array, like this:

```
b=numpy.array ([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,8,16]], dtype='float64')
```

Or if you want, add a **.0** to any of the numbers in your array to specify that you want to use float not int.

Comment: To add to it, I think the default is `int64` and if you want to check, overflow happens since `np.iinfo(np.int64).max/(16**16)` is smaller than one.

Comment: Actually, the dtype will be some integer dtype, but the exact size is platform-dependant, so whether it is a 64 bit vs a 32 bit architecture and the OS as well. Basically, it is whatever a C long is. Assuming a 64bit operating system, that is a 64bit integer on Linux, but a 32 bit integer on windows.

Comment: Also, you should just do `numpy.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,8,16]], dtype=numpy.float64)`